# rel and href match

Tags: jquery, href, rel

http://jsfiddle.net/aprWP/

```
<a href="#numtag-1">One</a>
<a href="#numtag-2">Two</a>
<a href="#numtag-3">Three</a>

<div class="numtag-1">One</div>
<div class="numtag-2">Two</div>
<div class="numtag-3">Three</div>
```

.. on hover  the appropriate div should toggle class 'active'.

Tried a lot of things but can't get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you want to hover over.

Comment: What exactly did you try btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a combination of hover event and toggleClass:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
    $('div.' + $(this).attr('href').substring(1)).toggleClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aprWP/7/

Changed to use substring as I think that's a better way of doing it.

Comment: I like short code. Short is good. (I would have used `.slice(1)` instead of `.replace('#','')`, though.)

Answer (score 2):

This is nice and easy. Use the `.hover()` event on the `a`, create the class from the `href` attribute of the `a`, and here you have it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").hover(function() {
        var str = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");

        $("div." + str).addClass("active");
    }, function() {
        var str = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");

        $("div." + str).removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Do bear in mind that you need to remove the `#` from the `href` attribute, hence the `.replace("#", "")` part.

Comment: No need to have two functions. Just use one and toggleClass. But +1 anyway as it works.

Comment: If you want to remove the class when the mouse leaves, you need two functions. If, as you said, you just want to toggle a class when the mouse enters the `a`, one is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('a').hover(function() {
        var selector = 'div.' + $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
        $(selector).addClass('active');
    }, function() {
        var selector = 'div.' + $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
        $(selector).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aprWP/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').hover(function() {
       var id = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
       $('.' + id).addClass('active'); 
    }, function() {
       var id = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
       $('.' + id).removeClass('active');        
    });
});
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/aprWP/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('a').hover(function(){    
      var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
      var className = url.substring(1); 
      $('div.' + className).toggleClass('active'); 
    }); 
});
```